# Using shared memory segment in a DLL in 2 different processes

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, dll, shared-libraries

I have a shared DLL where I want to write a HWND into a global, shared section:

```
#pragma data_seg(".SHARED")
HWND g_shhWnd = NULL;
#pragma data_seg()
#pragma comment(linker, "/section:.SHARED,RWS")
```

Process 1 loads the DLL (LoadLibrary) and calls MainLoop from the DLL, waiting for a WM_QUERYWND. Once it is received, it writes its own HWND into the global, shared variable g_shhWnd.

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) MainLoop()
{
  // contains huge bunch of stuff: creates a window, message loop & window handler
  // window handler contains:
  case WM_QUERYWND:
    g_shhWnd = myCurrentWnd;
  // ...
}
```

Process 2 loads the DLL LoadLibrary) and calls GetMyWnd():

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) HWND GetMyWnd()
{
  UINT WM_QUERYWND = RegisterWindowMessage(WM_QUERWND_GUID);
  SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_QUERWND, 0, 0);
  return g_shhWnd;
}
```

This function isses a WM_QUERWND which causes process 1 to write the current HWND into g_shhWnd. This call is actually made and g_shhWnd actually written by process 1 (checked via MessageBox).

However, the return value from GetMyWnd in process 2 is always zero (of course, g_shhWnd is zero after SendMessage returns).

I would expect that g_shhWnd is shared across all instances which exist from this DLL.

Is there anything missing or how could one proceed with debugging?

Comment: Did you check whether g_shhWnd is changed some time later (not just immediately after sending HWND_BROADCAST), to see whether this is some memory access/optimization issue? Also, I think, WM_QUERWND is a typo.

Comment: Side note: as it's the same DLL, GetMyWnd could "knows" the class name, and should use FindWindow and then SendMessage with the returned handle. Broadcasting with "send" all top levels should be avoided.